# Display Image Preview instead of text

Tags: javascript

We are trying to upload an image to our site.

1. We click on "**Upload Image**" button.

[image]

2. Then it displays **pop up** box.

[image]

3. Then we click on **Upload New image** button
4. After that, we will select image from computer & displaying message **Image uploaded**

[image]

Instead of message "Image uploaded", i want to **display preview of Uploaded image** as like this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/)

code to display message "Image uploaded"

```
<input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" class="newcustomimage" name="new_image" value=""/>
```

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('body').delegate('.newcustomimage', 'change', function () {
        if(jQuery(this).val()) {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="add_image_2508269_success" class="success-message validation-advice"> Image Uploaded.</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

I did below changes for above code to display "**Image Preview**" instead of message. Now Image preview is not displaying after we upload image. Instead its displaying like below image before we uploading an image in site.

[image]

```
<input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" class="newcustomimage" name="new_image" value=""/>
<img id="blah" src="http://example.com/media/custom_product_preview/quote" />
```

**Js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('body').delegate('.newcustomimage', 'change', function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val()) {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="add_image_2508269_success" class="success-message validation-advice"> Image Uploded.</div>');
   }
});

function readURL(input) { 
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Checked the console for any error?

Comment: inspect the `blah` image element, copy paste the src, and tell us what you find.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen There is no console error in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

Comment: I opened that in my browser and it says there's nothing there. Where do you get that from?

Comment: may be our [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) is blocked by firewall

Comment: The path `http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/custom_product_prev‌​iew/quote` doesn't point to an image. It is a folder full of images. You need the full path to the image file.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov thanks , can you please tell me how to get correct path.....

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 just add the filename to the directory, e.g. `http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/custom_product_prev‌​iew‌​/quote/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME.png`

Comment: @goldylucks i tried like this , but that did't worked for me : `http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/custom_product_prev‌​iew‌​‌​/quote/$filename`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do that please follow below

add this in your **html**

```
<input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" data-rand={{rand}} class="newcustomimage" name="new_image" onchange="readURL(this);" value=""  />

<img id="previewImg" src="#" style="display: none;height: 200px; width: 200px;" >
```

The **java script** for the same will be.

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) { 

        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery('#previewImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
            jQuery('#previewImg').show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

This will work in your case please have a try.

Comment: i will check and let you know, Thanks for your time....

Comment: Yes take your time

Comment: please upload any image  [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) and click Add image, after that again click on "upload image" , than old image preview is still visible, i dont want to display the old preview once i uploaded image....  http://prnt.sc/e91mwf

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working fine. Just need to configure the dimensions of the image.

Apply the following css:

```
.tool-body.selected {
    text-align: center;
}

#previewImg {
    height: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also correct the spelling of **uploaded**.

**EDIT**

The following code works perfectly for the OP and meets his requirement:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').on('.newcustomimage', 'change', function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val()) {
            console.log(jQuery(this).val());
            if (jQuery(this).val()) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
            }

            jQuery(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="add_image_2508269_success" class="success-message validation-advice"> Image Uploaded.</div>');
        }
    });

    jQuery(".aitcg-button").click(function() {
        jQuery('#previewImg').hide();
    });
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            jQuery('#previewImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
            jQuery('#previewImg').show();
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

The screengrab to the working site can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvvEc.jpg).

Comment: i will check and let you know, Thanks for your time....

Comment: You are welcome! 

Comment: please upload any image  [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) and click Add image, after that again click on "upload image" , than old image preview is still visible, i dont want to display the old preview once i uploaded image....  http://prnt.sc/e91mwf

Comment: The old preview disappears and the new preview appears when I upload a new image.

Comment: okay, upload one image and click on add image, again click on `add image`, there you can see preview of `old image` but it should't visible at that time.....

Comment: Thanks a ton for your support , sorry, that i accepted other answer because it gave me solution to solve main issue..... but still i need to find solution for [link5](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="add_image_{{rand}}" class="newcustomimage" name="new_image" value=""/>
<div id="imgcontaner"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".newcustomimage").change(function() {
   var input = this;
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
                $("#imgcontaner").empty();
                $('<img/>').appendTo("#imgcontaner")
                           .attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ,  updated your code, still issue is there ...... can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) and help me why i am getting issue as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344606/hide-preview-of-image-once-it-uploaded)

Comment: Hi, You just use this code 

$("#imgcontaner").empty(); 
when the popup is closed.

Comment: thanks, let me check that now.....

Comment: hi, i am already using that code, can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) once or is i am using that code in wrong place ?

Comment: can you please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136305/save

Comment: Thanks a ton for your support , sorry, that i accepted other answer because it gave me solution to solve main issue..... but still i need to find solution for [link5](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Answer (score 0):

You have not called function on file select. You need to change it like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
      jQuery('body').delegate('.newcustomimage', 'change', function (){
       if (jQuery(this).val())
          {
             readURL(jQuery(this));
          }
      });
  });
```

keep there readurl function outside jQuery(document).ready

```
     function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
```

Comment: i am checking, let you know soon.....

Comment: can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) , `upload image` button not working, seems i am missing somewhere....

Comment: there are some console error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 missing closing breces at end.

Comment: sory, let me check that......

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 add } at end readURL function

Comment: updated closing braces , please check link, now `upload image` button displaying.... now  once i upload image, i need to display `preview of image`

Comment: Thanks a ton for your support , sorry, that i accepted other answer because it gave me solution to solve main issue..... but still i need to find solution for [link5](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) , Thanks again for your continous support and need your support like same in future also......