# Hide Preview of image once it uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

we are uploading an image from [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

[image]

Before displaying in site, we are displaying **Preview** of the image as below :

[image]

after this, we click on add image and display image in site.

[image]

now we want to upload new 2nd image, so when we click on "**Upload image**" button , again the old image is still displaying as **preview**, but i want to hide that.....

[image]

```
<img id="previewImg" src="#" style="display: none;height: 100px; width: 100px;" >
```

**script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{ 
jQuery('body').delegate('.newcustomimage', 'change', function () { 
if (jQuery(this).val()) { 
console.log(jQuery(this).val());
if(jQuery(this).val()){
    var reader = new FileReader();       
}

jQuery(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="add_image_2508269_success" class="success-message validation-advice"> Image Uploded.</div>'); 
} 
}); 
}); 

function readURL(input) {
jQuery('#previewImg').hide();
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) { 

        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery('#previewImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
            jQuery('#previewImg').show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

mainly i am using this code to hide preview of image , but that is not working :

```
jQuery('#previewImg').hide();
```

also tried below code to hide :

```
jQuery(document).on(".aitcg-button", "click", function() {
    jQuery('#aitcg-tool-UserImage #previewImg')[0].hide();
});
```

Comment: Try to move the `readURL()` function inside `jQuery(document).ready(function (){})` function.

Comment: Can you provide snippet with your code?

Comment: @Kinduser Thanks i tried your suggestion, but now `image preview` is not displaying for the first time also..... i reverted code now.....

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for suggestion, i will try to add snippet now.....

Comment: i tried to create snippet , as we are using plugin & it included lof of html code in js file, when i created fiddle it did`t gave me any output.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to execute this perfectly you need to append whole new image block on uploade image and to hide it remove whole block on "Add Image" action success(where you hide save button).

Comment: Thanks dear. Go ahead.